# jQuery hover - div with dynamic id - mouseover works, mouseout doesn't

Tags: jquery

I have a page of thumbnails - when I hover over each one, a box of text is displayed. When I mouseout the box should disappear. When I hardcode this it all works well. However when I try and use dynamic variables it shows but does not hide the text box

here is my code

```
$(function() {

$('[id^=trigger]').hover(function () {
var roll =  this.id.replace(/trigger/, 'roll');
      $('#' + roll).show();
      }, function() { 
      $('#' + roll).hide(); 
});
```

});

and here is my html

```
<div id='trigger".$id."' style='width:300px;height:200px;'><img src='http://www.example.com/uploads/".$id."/0.jpg'></div><div id='roll".$id."' style='background-color:#ffffff;display:none;width:284px;position:absolute;top 300px;padding:8px;'><h1 class='h1box'>$title</h1><p class='pbox'$text</p></div>
```

So basically the id for each image will be trigger1, trigger 2 etc and for the text box roll1, roll2 etc

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just add a class to your div? That lookup is much cheaper I think. Is the element you are hiding/showing always the next element?

Comment: Thanks - that's great - learning all the time! - no the id's will depend on what was called from the database - not necessarily consequitive values. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `roll` in your `mouseleave` is undefined. That is because you are only setting it in your `mouseenter`. You have to define the same variable in the `mouseleave` function:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[id^=trigger]').hover(function() {
    var roll = this.id.replace(/trigger/, 'roll');
    $('#' + roll).show();
  }, function() {
    var roll = this.id.replace(/trigger/, 'roll');
    $('#' + roll).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='trigger1' style='width:300px;height:200px;'>
  <img src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=300&h=200'>
</div>
<div id='roll1' style='background-color:#ffffff;display:none;width:284px;position:absolute;top 300px;padding:8px;'>
  <h1 class='h1box'>title</h1>
  <p class='pbox'>
    test
  </p>
</div>
```